# SSRS 2008 R2 Parameters (location)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

All I am trying to do is to change the location of the "Parameters" from the right side to the top on the SharePoint Site. Is this possible? [image]

I am using Visual Studio to Deploy this report, and under the preview mode the parameters show as desired:

Using a Page Viewer web part, I am able to display the report as desired. 
However, I get a second login. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: You do know you can just click the line with the arrow on it between the report and the parameters pane and the parameters pane will hide itself, leaving more room to view the report? Click again to open it again.

Comment: @MicroSumol Could you please tell me how you could display the report with top parameter panel? Mine is still at right side even if I applied "Page Viewer" Web Part instead of SSRS web part.... THX!!!